# Can I use red clay bricks for an organic veggie raised bed? What about mortar?

Tags: vegetables, raised-beds

I am trying to find an inexpensive but attractive way to put a raised bed in that will be used for an organic veggie garden.  It sounds as if clay bricks are OK if they haven't been in a fireplace.  What about the mortar?  What do I need to look for?

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard anything about standard mortar mix that would be harmful to vegetables. A bag of mortar mix at your local hardware store will be relatively inexpensive.

Also, take a look at [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2552/which-techniques-and-tools-should-i-use-to-build-a-raised-vegetable-garden-from?rq=1) for some tips on building a raised bed with bricks.